# Codeigniter : How to redirect to main page if there is no data to load again?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I'm on online quiz project, one page one question. And i have problem when there's no question to load, i don't understand how to redirect to main page

Comment: `header("Location: your full url of home page"); exit;`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the **redirect** method.

```
redirect('controller/action');
```

Comment: Link to docs: [`redirect()`](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)